# Dynamic Footer Links Magento

Tags: php, magento, hyperlink, content-management-system

Hi I have a magento site in Magento 1.6.2.0 . I want to set up my footer links according to my categories that i have created . I added one of the link in my 'footer cms'

```
<li><a href="#">Living Room Furniture</a></li>
```

how can I place the link (href) by using category ID/Name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in footer.phtml

```
  <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?> 
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to call a template file through CMS.

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="folder/filename.phtml"}}
```

In that file you can do code to list the category.

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php foreach ($_helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?> 
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

It list only the main categories under the root category